# RegEx (in JavaScript find/replace) - match non-alphanumeric characters but ignore - and +

Tags: javascript, regex, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric

We have been using the following js/regex to find and replace all non-alphanumeric characters apart from - and +

```
outputString = outputString.replace(/[^\w|^\+|^-]*/g, "");
```

However it doesn't work entirely - it doesn't replace the ^ and | characters. I can't help but wonder if this is something to do with the ^ and | being used as meta-characters in the regex itself.

I've tried switching to use `[\W|^+|^-]`, but that replaces the - and +. I thought that possibly a lookahead assertion may be the answer, but I'm not very sure how to implement them.

Has anyone got an idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Character classes do not do alternation, hence why the `|` is literal, and the `^` must be at the start of the class to take effect (otherwise it's treated literally.)

Use this:

```
[^\w+-]+
```

(Also, if `-` is not last, it needs to be escaped as `\-` inside a character class - so be careful if more characters might be added to the exception list).

You could also do it with a negative lookahead like this:

```
(?![+-])\W
```

Note: You do not want a `*` or `+` after that `\W`, since the lookahead only applies to the immediately following character (and the `g` flag makes the replace repeat until done).

Also note that `\w` and `\W` consider `_` as a word character. If that's not desired then to replace that you can use `(?![+-])[\W_]` (or use explicit ranges in the first expressions).

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks - that's great. <code>[^\w+-]+</code> worked just great! And thanks for the additional information - very helpful.